# Chaining a constructor with an object function call in PHP

Tags: php

Does anyone know if the following expression will be possible in the next version(s) of PHP?

```
(new A())->a();    // Causes a syntax error
```

I find very annoying that currently one must write 2 lines instead of 1:

```
$c = new A();
$c->a();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to chain method on a newly created object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188629/how-to-chain-method-on-a-newly-created-object)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first version does not cause a parse error, it is perfectly valid. The second it is, indeed not possible, but you can easily overcome such a problem with some coding standards.

If every team member creates, for each defined class, a function with the same name as the class, and a signature similar to the signature of the class constructor, then you won't have the second problem. Example:

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct($param)
    {}

    public function bar()
    {}
}

/**
 * @return Foo
 */
function Foo($param)
{
    return new Foo($param);
}

Foo()->bar();
```

Of course, you'll still have problems with library code.

Comment: Right, the first one is non-issue. I must have confused it with something else. I'll edit the question. Thanks

Comment: I think you confused it with functionReturnsArray()[3], which is indeed not possible. There have been proposals, but they didn't get accepted. PHP internals don't like that shortcut.

Comment: Iount: do you have any links to the discussing regarding this? This is a feature I really miss :(

Comment: http://markmail.org/message/kk2hwn3gdjcw2yfh#query:related%3Akk2hwn3gdjcw2yfh+page:1+mid:5bv6mtd7zorni7gc+state:results

http://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing

Comment: Can anyone tell me if this is a common idiom in PHP? Do people often do this,that is define a global fn that returns the object?

Comment: No, it's not a common idiom. I've seen it used by me and just one other person.

Comment: "The first version does not cause a parse error, it is perfectly valid." Wish Stack Overflow had visible revisions so I could see what you're talking about here before it was edited. EDIT: Found them! Just need to click on the date. <3

Answer (score 6):

A new-expression can be used as a function argument. A function call can be used as the left-hand side of the member access operator. Therefore, you just need to define a single function:

```
function with($object) { return $object; }

with(new A()) -> a();
```

No additional efforts required on a per-class basis.

Comment: I like this, although it ends up being a bit weird if you also need a reference to the object for later use. Unless the method(s) you call return a reference to the object (e.g. are specifically chainable), then you need to do `with($my_object = new A())->a();`. But it's a novel way around a limitation, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible as of [PHP 5.4+](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php):

> Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. (new Foo)->bar().