# Is using the indirection operator twice in a statement a good practise?

Tags: php, oop

Sometimes I see things like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("menupro/menu")->setGroup_id(5)->setTemplate("menupro/menupro.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

I was wondering whether this is a good practise?

Comment: Fluent interface can be very easy to read, though not typically when it's all on one line; but does have potential drawbacks if any of the methods throws an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather subjective question, I personally am all for it. You can make your code a lot more readable. Check out this link: 
[Effects of method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821762/effects-of-method-chaining)

The major drawback is that you must return the object. You may not return any other value as you’re only allowed to return $this.