# Why is this not valid PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: How to chain method on a newly created object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188629/php-how-to-chain-method-on-a-newly-created-object)

I started off with this code:

```
$page = new Page();

$page->replace_tags(...);

$page->output();
```

I changed the signature of `replace_tags` to allow method chaining, by returning `$this`. Why can I still not write it like this?

```
new Page()->replace_tags(...)->output();
```

Or this:

```
(new Page())->replace_tags(...)->output();
```

Comment: u need to assign your instance to a value before calling its methods

Comment: @Ben: Why? Can't I use it as an expression?

Comment: See the question I linked above, it is a limitation of PHP syntax. You cannot chain a call to "new".

Comment: @Eric: no you cant. you also cant do things like `$obj->toArray()[0]`

Comment: It will come with PHP5.4, but for now its just not supported, because its just the way it is.

Comment: @prodigitalson: Yeah, that bugged me as well. Is there any documentation on why that doesn't work?

Comment: @Eric: It doesn't work because nobody implemented it yet. No documentation needed for something, that doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the object to a reference first:

```
$obj = new Page();
$obj->replace_tags(...)->output();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to chain the functions on the class instance:

```
$page = new Page();

$page->replace_tags(...)->output();
```