# Shorthand new Instance->Method syntax in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, shorthand

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: How to chain method on a newly created object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188629/php-how-to-chain-method-on-a-newly-created-object)

I can create an instance and call it's method via:

```
$newObj = new ClassName();
$newObj -> someMethod();
```

But is there any way I can do it in a shorter notation, an anonymous instance? I tried this:

```
(new ClassName())->someMethod();
```

But it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Additional Info: The method I want to call is public but not static.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188629/php-how-to-chain-method-on-a-newly-created-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that i know of.

But! - You could implement a Singleton Pattern and then call:

```
ClassName::getInstance()->someMethod();
```

Or, to cut it short ;)

```
ClassName::gI()->someMethod();
```

If someMethod does not refer to $this, you could also simply call it as a static function, though it wasn't defined as one:

```
ClassName::someMethod();
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can only have one singleton. I'm afraid this is a regular object, some will be anonymous, but some will be stored in containers or arrays or even other objects. Unless I can make getInstance return a new instance of the object.. I'll try it.

Comment: It worked perfectly! My constructor has optional params, so I had to include those in my getInstance() class when it made a new instance and returned it, but it definitely worked. Thanks. My chains look a lot cleaner now. I'll accept as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 5):

PHP 5.4 supports it.

If you can't update you can workaround like this:

```
function yourclass($param) {
   return new yourclass($param);
}

yourclass()->method();
```

Don't forget that your constructor must `return $this;`

Answer (score 0):

If the method is static and doesn't rely on any class variables (maybe you've put it in a class just for organisation purposes), you can simply call it staticly as phil is demonstrating with getInstance:

```
ClassName::someMethod()
```